# Ventanas sin bordes en pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Logré quitarle los bordes a mi ventana principal pero ahora no la puedo mover con el ratón.

Esto es lo que usé para ello:

```
self.setWindowFlags((Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
```

¿Cómo puedo volver a moverla sin los bordes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobreescribe los siguientes métodos [Fuente](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/widgets/shapedclock.py):

```
   def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()
```

Tengo un proyecto que hace lo que tu deseas, puedes tomarlo como ejemplo, lo uso en la clase Background https://github.com/CodeHuntersLab/CuriElements:

Comment: Gracias men tal ves te quieras unir a mi grupo de pyqt en telegram

Comment: Es este   https://telegram.me/joinchat/CKcrRT_zUiroJBFjng-Meg

Comment: @Python si me respuesta te ayudo podrías marcarla como correcta.

Comment: @Python ya me uni desde hace unos momentos

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te pongo todas las opciones disponibles listadas en [la documentación](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html):

```
Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint;
Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint;
Qt::FramelessWindowHint;
Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint;
Qt::WindowTitleHint;
Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint;
Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint;
Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint;
Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
Qt::WindowShadeButtonHint;
Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint;
Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint;
Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;
```

En tu caso concreto entiendo que quieres utilizar **varios flags** a la vez para conseguir lo que quieres. Por ejemplo, en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997915/1468942) exponen:

Si la ventana es un widget:

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Si es una Window normal:

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Si es un *dialog*:

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Comment: sigo con el mismo fallo creo q no se puede @Miguel Coll